# Time distribution: is it possible to determine whether calls are human-made or machine-made by patterns of the distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions

I'm relatively new to statistics, so the question is primarily about your advice on where I should start with this problem and read related material.

So, suppose I've got a temporal distribution of phone calls of a suspicious subscriber, a very basic one with just a timestamp of a successful phone call and a duration of it:

```
timestamp:duration
timestamp:duration 
...
```

The task is to test whether this subscriber is a bot (a machine) or a human.
Can you judge from such a distribution if a subscriber is indeed a human or a bot?

I've got distributions of other subscribers, a lot of them, and they are indeed human.

Is there a way I could compare phone call patterns of real humans with this suspicious distribution to tell if it resembles human behaviour?

Should I employ Poisson distribution for such a test instead?

What is the correct toolbox for such a task?
Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Edited it a little, maybe it's clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

Over the short term the answer is **maybe**. If we assume **yes**, then as soon as it becomes possible to model human-made calling patterns versus machine-made calling patterns, that very model can be used to generate machine-made calling patterns which are indistinguishable from human ones.

Over the long term, if being undifferentiable from human-made calling patterns provides some advantage to the owners or managers of machine callers, then the answer will become **no** as machine-call patterns camouflage themselves to be indistinguishable from human-made.

Comment: So, if I am to strive to achieve that, what should I do? Should I model for time between calls, for example, and view it as an exponential distribution, and then test if my distribution is different from that of real people?